# Javascript Regular Exception Matching a String Once Every Two Attempts in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, google-chrome

I have the following regular expression in javascript :

```
var the_regexp = /^\/([!\/]*)\/?(\w*)\??([\=|\w]*)\/?$/gi
```

It Firefox and Chrome console, it find a match for the string "/d" once every two attemps.

```
>the_regexp
/^\/([!\/]*)\/?(\w*)\??([\=|\w]*)\/?$/gi
>the_regexp.exec("/d")
null
>the_regexp.exec("/d")
["/d", "", "d", ""]
>the_regexp.exec("/d")
null
>the_regexp.exec("/d")
["/d", "", "d", ""]
```

Can somebody explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec
>   method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>   When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by
>   the regular expression's lastIndex property

So when your regex has a g flag, and you use the exec method once, the next time you execute it it will search for a match after the first match. In this case, there is none: exec will return null and the lastIndex property will be reset.

For example:

```
var str = "abcdef";
//         ^ starting index for search is here
var regex = /ab/g;

regex.exec(str);
// str: "abcdef"
//         ^ starting index for search is now here

regex.exec(str);
// no match found from starting index, return null and reset
// str: "abcdef"
//       ^ starting index reset
```

I'm sorry for my bad wordings etc, I'm not fully awake...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the g flag from your Regex, depending on what you want to achieve. Also, those empty capturing groups look kind of unnecessary.

EDIT: Looks like Reanimation beat me ;)